# Откуда пошла манера говорить "знать за кого-то" или "пояснять за что-то"?

Tags: жаргон

Насколько это грамотно? Какова история употребления "за" в подобных контекстах?

Comment: Украинизмы, южнорусские диалекты. Нелитературные.

Answer (score 1):

Как и сказано в комментарии, "за" - привет с Украйны.

Но и в современном молодёжном сленге можно встретить:

> [«Пояснить за шмот»](https://www.kp.ru/daily/26699.7/3723381/) значит объяснить, какое ты право имеешь носить
>   то, что сейчас на тебе надето. Не сможешь — тебя побьют.

[Ещё](https://mel.fm/pravopisaniye/638529-miss_u):

> В современном русском языке считается, что «скучаю по вас» — старая
>   норма. Хотя в том же справочнике Розенталя можно встретить замечание о
>   том, что с существительными и местоимениями третьего лица верно
>   говорить: скучать по кому/чему. А вот в первом и втором лице будет
>   «скучать по ком»: по нас, по вас. Варианты до сих пор конкурируют, и в
>   некоторых словарях рядом с фразой «скучаю по вас» стоит помета
>   «устарелое». В нашем случае — «скучать по тебе» — во всех падежах
>   будет однозначно. ***Но что определённо грамотному человеку делать
>   нельзя, так скучать за кем-то или за чем-то. Это скорее привет соседям
>   с Украины, чей говор, так или иначе, можно встретить и в русском
>   языке.***